# Visual Studio creates (empty) folder in /bin for build action "Content" while publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, publishing, vs-web-application-project

I have a Web Application Project in Visual Studio 2005 that I publish using "Project" -> "Publish".

The App uses some (text) files that live in a top-level folder; let us call it `textfiles` for example.

What I would like to achieve is that Visual Studio creates a top-level folder called `textfiles` on the target when publishing. The folder should contain the text files it contains on my local machine when publishing.

I got pretty close by setting the "Build Action" to "Content" and the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Do not copy" in the settings of the text files. This makes VS create a top-level folder called `textfiles` that contains the files I want. But it also creates an empty `textfiles`-folder in /bin, which I do not want/need.

Is there a way to have VS ditch the empty folder? Preferably without a post build event (is that how you call those?). I felt like "Do not copy" should do the trick...

By the way the other settings I use for publishing are "Delete all existing files" and "Only files needed"; Include App_Code is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Open your proj file in notepad and search for "Copy to Output Directory" node.Delete it and try.